# LevelDB: Lifetime and responsibility of comparators, block_cache and filter_policy?

Tags: c++, database, lifetime, leveldb

Do I need to delete my comparators, block_cache and filter_policy after closing my database? Do they need to exist during the lifetime of the database?

I cannot find this info in any of the documentation.

From looking at the source code, I'm guessing that I need to delete them after closing the database but they need to persist during the lifetime while it's open.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`options.block_cache` and `options.filter_policy` must be deleted after closing the database handles.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about comparators but I'm not sure about the other two.